# monaca の localstorage で resources に載っているのに取得できない

Tags: javascript, monaca, html5

monaca で localStorage を使用しているのですが、localStorage.setItem で保存し、
resources に表示されているデータを取得しようとしても、null が返ってきてしまいます。

setItem した直後に getItem にて console.logを確認すると、その時はlogに中身が表示されるのですが、違う関数から取得しようとしてもnullにしかならず原因がわかりません

どのようなことが考えられるでしょうか？
ご教授お願いいたします

コードを追記いたしました
①の時は、localStorageから取得できるのですが、②の時はnullになってしまいます

更に追記いたしました
17行目に、変数xxxのコードを書き忘れておりました

```
//①
function dataload(){
  var httpobj = jQuery.get("./data/000.txt",null,function(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseTabText(httpobj.responseText);
  });
}
function parseTabText(tabText){
  var resultText = "<table border='0' cellspacing='0' class='sampletable'>";
  var LF = String.fromCharCode(10);
  var TAB = String.fromCharCode(9);
  lineData = tabText.split(LF);
  findText = document.ajaxForm.requestText.value;
  for (var i=0; i<lineData.length; i++){
    itemData = lineData[i].split(TAB);
    str = itemData[0].match(findText);
    if (str){
    var xxx = itemData[2];//ここを入れ忘れておりました
      resultText += '<tr><td>'+itemData[0]+'</td><td>'+itemData[1]+'</td><td>点</td><td onclick="searchpage2('+itemData[2]+')">詳 細</td></tr>';
      localStorage.setItem(xxx,JSON.stringify(itemData));
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(xxx))); //この段階では正しく表示されます
    }
  }
  resultText += "</table>";
  return resultText;
}

//②
function searchpage2(xxx){
  var options =  {
    animation:'lift',
    onTransitionEnd:function(){
      var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(xxx));
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(xxx)));//ここではnull
      document.getElementById("memoA").innerHTML = data;
    }
  };
  myNavigator.pushPage('page2_memoedit.html',options);
}
```

Comment: 現象を再現できるコードを記載してください。

Comment: monaca タグをつけていただいたり、見やすくコードを編集していただき、皆様ありがとうございます。
for (key in localStorage) {
if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
console.log(key);
}
}
にて、Keyを確認して、変数ではなくそのKeyを直接入力してもnulｌが返ってきてしまいます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<td onclick="searchpage2('+itemData[2]+')">詳 細</td>`が原因です。

例えば、`itemData[2]`の値が`'0'`の場合、`searchpage2('0')`ではなく`searchpage2(0)`となります。
`searchpage2()`の引数`xxx`には数値の`0`が渡るので、`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(xxx))`は`null`が返ってきます。
`itemData[2]`の値が英字の文字列だと、英字の文字列という名の変数が定義されていないとエラーになります。

この場合、文字列がシングルクォーテーションで囲ってあるので、その中にシングルクォーテーションを書くときはバックスラッシュ(￥マーク)を先頭に付けます。

```
  resultText += '<tr><td>'+itemData[0]+'</td><td>'+itemData[1]+'</td><td>点</td><td onclick="searchpage2(\''+itemData[2]+'\')">詳 細</td></tr>';
```

Comment: ありがとうございます
javascriptで動的に生成することの動きが、まだよくわかっておらずとても参考になりました

ありがとうございました

閲覧してくださった方々も、本当にありがとうございます

Comment: GapDebugを使ってデバッグすれば、ブレイクポイントを置いてステップ実行できるので解決しやすいと思います。

Comment: ご親切に何度もありがとうございます
GapDebug　活用してみたいと思います
いろいろ教えていただきありがとうございました